# Jquery characters exceeding characters, show positive value then?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model-view-controller

Currently whats happening in this function is that when the characters exceed over 2000, it starts showing -x amount of characters remaining i.e. -1 characters remaining. I want it to i.e. when the characters exceed over 2000 I want it to show 1 characters over the limit etc...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var text_max = 2000;
  $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_max + ' character available.');

  $('#YourMessage').keyup(function() {
    var text_length = $('#YourMessage').val().length;
    var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;

    $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining.');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="YourMessage"></textarea><br/> <span id="textarea_feedback"></span>
```

Comment: @Ryan can you show me this on the above please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version that will get the absolute value of the remaining.
If the remaining are above 0 it shows one text, below another

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var text_max = 20;
  $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_max + ' characters available.');

  $('#YourMessage').keyup(function() {
    var text_length = $('#YourMessage').val().length;
    var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;
    var characters = " character"+(Math.abs(text_remaining)==1?"":"s");
    $('#textarea_feedback').html(Math.abs(text_remaining) + characters + (text_remaining > 0? ' remaining.':' over the limit.'));
    $('#textarea_feedback').toggleClass("red",text_remaining<0).toggleClass("green",text_remaining>=0)
  });
});
```

```css
.red { color:red; }
.green { color:green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="YourMessage"></textarea><br/> <span class="green" id="textarea_feedback"></span>
```

Comment: that works however how do I show the characters over the limit in red and the positive numbers in red? @mplungjan

Comment: In green you mean.

Comment: that works however how do I show the numbers and characters over the limit in red text? @mplungjan

Comment: when it exceeds the character limit i want the message to show in red

Comment: The code does this first the characters available are 20, then when you type something in the text box this changes to green.

Comment: And what do you want? You can just remove the class green from the span and remove the `.toggleClass("green",text_remaining>=0)` to not have green